# How to dynamically change default value of the drop down field of the gravity forms depending on the selection before landing on the form page

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, dynamic-values

I have a page with a pricing table:

- plan A
- plan B
- plan C

I want to use only one gravity form with a drop down default value filled depending on what the user have selected.

For example, if the user selected 'plan B' from the pricing table, the form will show the drop down 'plan B' selected by default.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

In Gravity Forms for your dropdown you will have a value. I found that as long as the value was one word it was easy to get it to be the default.

For you I would name each of your three things PlanA, PlanB, PlanC

Make sure show values is checked if you want it to be required.

Go over to the Advanced tab check the "Allow field to be populated dynamically" box and then for the parameter name enter a variable. I used default_value. Then on your different Plan names in your table you will need to add this. `<a href="planForm/?default_value=PlanA">Plan A</a>`

where "planForm" is obviously the link of your page and the default_value is equal to the value of the dropdown item you wish to be default.